# postgres: index on function age: ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

i am trying to add a function index with age on a column DATE doing:

`create index index_test on utenti(EXTRACT(year FROM AGE(birthday)));`

is there are way to make it works?

EDIT:
thinking that it could be dued to time zone i tried this
`create index index_test on utenti(EXTRACT(year FROM AGE(birthday AT TIME ZONE 'utc')));`

but i still get the same error

Comment: The result of this calculation might change tomorrow, how should the DBMS deal with it? How do you want to use it? It's probably better to have an index on `birthday` and then use `where birthday between .. and ...`

Comment: @dnoeth i have a column date storing birthdates and in my query i do `where age between x and y`. using postgres it is `WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM AGE(birthday)) between x and y` but i would like to create an index on ages and not dates because my query where uses ages

Comment: No,there is no way to make this work. The index stores the position of a row containing a certain value. This is impossible if the value can change without the actual row changing.

Comment: @wildplasser ah ok thank you. i didn't know it wasn't possible

Comment: It's easy to calculate the range of dates for a given age, e.g. `where birthday > current_date - interval '31 year' and birthdate <= current_date - interval '25 year'` to get all people between 25 and 30